# $S$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $k,m,l\in\mathbb{N}$, $m\ge k$ and a set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^m$. Suppose we have $S\times\mathbb{R}^l$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k+l}$, is it true that  $S$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$? Or is there any counterexample?

(It is just a question come up to my mind, so there is no references I can give. I have thought about it for a while without any progress.)

Comment: What is S? Generalised sphere?please mention.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan S could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S=$ Whitehead manifold, then $S= S^3-W$ where $W$ is Whitehead Continuum. Then Morton Brown shows that $S\times \mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$. But we know that $S$ is not homeomorphic with $\mathbb R^3$.